# Microsoft Visual Studio fails to publish

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, publish

I am trying to publish my project in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. I have debugged it and it is working as intended. When I attempt to publish it it builds successfully then fails to publish. I have opened the output window to see what is happening. This is what it says in the output window:

```
------ Build started: Project: JBIPP, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
  JBIPP -> J:\Bridges\Code\JBIPPDEV\WebApplication2\bin\WebApplication2.dll
------ Publish started: Project: JBIPP, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Connecting to \\IIS2dev\JBIPP...
Unable to create the Web site '\\IIS2dev\JBIPP'.  The path '\\IIS2dev\JBIPP' does not exist or you do not have access. The specified path is invalid.
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any suggestions on how to get this thing published would be appreciated.

Comment: Well `The path '\\IIS2dev\JBIPP' does not exist` so *start* -> *run*, paste in that path and see what happens - if it prompts for credentials then logon and try again.

Comment: Sorry, JBIPP is a dummy name. I changed it in my question for privacy reasons.

Comment: Well, whatever the real UNC path is then - you need to ensure its accessible